# QQ - small, unidentifiable icons on desktop

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, display, icons, desktop-environments

Running QQ with Nautilus.  Display is 1280 x 1024 - ViewSonic, recognized by QQ.

When I put a file or folder on the desktop, the icon is incredibly **SMALL** nearly **INVISIBLE**. Have to go into the change icon size menu to change.

And even when I expand the icon, I have NO CLUE of what the file is or what it does - must go into the properties menu, open the folder or run the file and hope for the best.

This is very time consuming and a huge pain when you are developing with deadlines. Makes me want to go back to Windows.

**Icons should be LARGER by default and LABELED** - this is a big pain and waste of time: a desktop littered by tiny, unidentifiable icons: **virtually useless!**

How can this be fixed? Is there an option/setting I can change to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit > Preference > tab Views > Icon View Default :change the Default Zoom level in Nautilus file manager. Nautilus is on your desktop as well not only the default file browser.

Comment: Tnx - zoom was set at 33% - I set to 66% - OK now.